# Div not covering the whole page?

Tags: html, css

I have made a background that needs to cover the whole page. I know this is a simple question to most of you, but i have tried everything!!! Every time i try something, it just covers the parent div. I want it to cover the entire webpage! Here is what i have so far.

```
<div id="bkgrd" style="z-index: 9999; display: none; position:absolute;top:25%;left:25%;right:25%;
bottom:25%;
margin:auto;
min-width:50%;
min-height:50%; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.4;"></div>
```

Comment: div {height:100%;width:100%;}

Comment: Does the parent div also have `position:absolute` or `position:relative`? Can you show us a bit more markup?

Comment: @ubercooluk that still just covered the div

Comment: if the parent div does not cover the whole page the chils div would not,because the parent div is the container of the child div.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#bkgrd {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```